# Converting web page into UITableView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, html-parsing

I have an `UITableView` and I want to populate it with data from this page: http://tvgids.mobi/gids/ned1.php

My code:

```
NSURL *urlll = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:url]]; 
NSString *test = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:urlll];
UIAlertView *av = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"LOL" message:test delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Dismiss" otherButtonTitles:nil];
[av show];
[av release];
```

That part works, but the problem is: *How do I get the list of tv programs into an `UITableView`?*
I can't use an XML parse since the page isn't valid XML. Every single tv program on that page is written like this (in html):

```
<div class="v2-listing">
    <div class="v2-tijd">13:30</div>
    <div class="v2-omschrijving">
        <a href="http://tvgids.mobi/vanavond-op-tv/8428198-NOS_Sportjournaal.xhtml" >NOS Sportjournaal</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

I need to get v2-tijd (e.g. 13:30), and the `a`'s href (e.g. http://tvgids.mobi/vanavond-op-tv/8428198-NOS_Sportjournaal.xhtml) and content (e.g. NOS Sportjournaal).

How would I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would probably try using [RegExKit](http://regexkit.sourceforge.net/) or [RegExLite](http://regexkit.sourceforge.net/RegexKitLite/) to grep out what I needed, but that's probably not the best way.

Answer (score -1):

Use [`UIWebView`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) inside [`UITableViewCell`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: Man come on. Read my question -_-

Comment: Well after reading your question i said you that. I have gone through this problem where i have to my web page data in TableView, so how i can do this? 

Forget about UITableView and put UIWebView as subview of UIView, its like making a Browser inside your app.

Comment: Nope, I don't do that. I completely follow the iPhone Interface Guidelines and I don't want to fake native controls.